# Select based on age at time of record creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, compare, date

I work in a school district and we're looking to do a search to find all of the records where a student was between the ages of 3 and 5 during the time the record was created.  The important fields (as far as I know) would be...

Student Name
Date of Birth
Notice Date (which is the date the record was created)

So, basically, if the notice date was 1/5/2013, I'd want to pull the records for any kids whose DOB falls between 1/4/2008 and 1/5/2010

Any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this?

SQL Server 2005

Comment: Your prose says sql server and your tag says mysql.  The answer depends on your database engine.

Comment: Thanks for cleaning that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select [Student Name], [Date of Birth]
  from <however your table is named>
 where DateDiff(month, [Date of Birth], [Notice Date]) between 3 * 12 and 5 * 12 + 1
```

Comment: Just did some testing of this and it's working out perfectly.  Thanks much!